# NPE when populating HashMap within an object?

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, null, hashmap

I have the following object:

```
public class PersonDTO {

    private Map<String, String> idsAndNames;

    //default constructor
    public PersonDTO() {
    }

    public PersonDTO(Map<String, String> idsAndNames) {
        this.idsAndNames = idsAndNames;
    }

    public void setIdsAndNames(Map<String, String> idsAndNames) {
        this.idsAndNames = idsAndNames;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getIdsAndNames() {
        return idsAndNames;
    }


    public void addEntryToMap(String id, String name) {
        this.idsAndNames.put(id, name);
    }

}
```

Whenever I try to populate the `map` within the object (see method below), I get a `Null Pointer Exception` saying that the `Map` is `null`. How can I fix this?

**Method to populate object (within main class):**

```
public PersonDTO populatePersonDTO(List<String> ids, List<String> names){

        Map<String, String> idsAndNames = new HashMap<>();
        PersonDTO personDTO = new PersonDTO();
        personDTO.setIdsAndNames(idsAndNames);

        for(int i=0;i<ids.size();i++){

            personDTO.addEntryToMap(ids.get(i),names.get(i)); //line throwing NPE
        }
        return personDTO;
    }
```

**Calling populatePersonDTO:**

```
List<String> ids= Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> names= Arrays.asList("name1", "name2", "name3");

populatePersonDTO(ids, names);
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace of your Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: The code use posted must be different than the code you are running (or the problem is not in the code you posted). I tried to copy your `PersonDTO` as is and added `populatePersonDTO` as a static method of same class. When I call it from the main with the same snippet you posted, everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the NPE line points to `populatePersonDTO`, then `names` is the one being null (`ids` can't be since we're calling `ids.size()` w/o problem). If it was `idsAndNames` the NPE would point to `addEntryToMap` instead.

So make sure that `names` is not null.

Comment: the issue is that within the PersonDTO the idsAndNames map is null, but I cannot work out why?